# font size of one div not resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Why is one of my divs not resizing/being responsive on mobile?

Only one of the divs has a fixed font size, whereas all the other are responsive when using mobile :
[image]

Site viewable here :
[https://metriculous.network/](http://metriculous.network/)

Comment: I dont see any css related to responsive so just add like `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {#title{font-size: 20px;}}`

Comment: @TrầnTrịnhKuy the other divs are working as expected

Comment: its with the `button`, you remove it, or make it a div, things fall back as normal. Interesting bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the below to your `<head>`.

This would help correct the scaling of elements. *(your button had the issue with scaling, causing the div to scale lower than other elements in the page)*

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```